# React Context: TypeError: render is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to use React Context to pass a function to a nested child component, which effectively allows the child to update the parents state when pressed.

The problem is I seem to be getting an error **'TypeError: render is not a function. (In render(newValue), render is an instance of Array'** and an error in my console reads: **'Warning: A context consumer was rendered with multiple children, or a child that isn't a function. A context consumer expects a single child that is a function. If you did pass a function, make sure there is no trailing or leading whitespace around it.'**

I've looked around at this error and also at documentation but no answers seem to answer my question, I can't quite work out why this isn't working.

**EDIT:** I should add that there are multiple child components rendered, as they're built from an array of objects

Snippets:

Parent:

```
class Product extends Component {
    state = {
        selected_ind: 0
    };

    handleContextChange = selected_ind => {
        this.setState({selected_ind});
    };

    render() {
        const contextValue = {
            data: this.state,
            handleChange: this.handleContextChange
        };

        //Desconstruct props for ease of use
        const {
            attr_data,
            variant,
            product_name } = this.props;


        return (
                <Container>
                    <Heading>Product Options</Heading>
                    <IndexContext.Provider value={contextValue}>
                        <OptionTile
                            tileColor='grey'
                            onPress={ () => this.props.navigation.navigate('Variants', {
                                attr_data: attr_data,
                                selected_ind: this.state.selected_ind
                            })} //Replace with named function
                            option="Variant"
                            selected_ind={ this.state.selected_ind }
                            value={ selected_attr.name } />
                    </IndexContext.Provider>
                    <OptionTile
                        tileColor='grey'
                        option="Quantity"
                        value="1" />
                </Container>
```

Within OptionTile is the child I'd like to use the function within:

```
const VariantTile = (props) => {
    return (
        <IndexContext.Consumer>
            {({ handleChange }) => (
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleChange(props.index)}>
                    <AsyncImage
                        source={ props.img_src }
                        placeholderColor="#fafafa"
                        style={{ flex: 1, width: null, height: 200 }}
                    />
                    <Text>{ props.var_name }</Text>
                    <Text>{ props.price }</Text>
                    <Text>{ props.sku }</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            )};
        </IndexContext.Consumer>
    )
};
```

And the context component is simple:

```
const IndexContext = React.createContext();

export default IndexContext;
```

Comment: `<VariantTile>` is a child of `<OptionTile>`?

Comment: Could you provide a minimal reproducible working example? It's hard to fill in the missing pieces at the moment.

Comment: VariantTile is a child of VariantScreen, OptionTile navigates to the VariantScreen navigation stack

Comment: Sounds as if the Consumer isn't sitting inside the Provider scope, hence cannot access it. Could you share minimal repository?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

As the error states, `<Consumer>` should have the only child, and it should be a function. The error appears when it has multiple children, including text nodes.

`;` after embedded expression causes the problem. It's not a part of an expression, and making it a part of it would result in syntax error.

It should be:

```
<IndexContext.Consumer>
    {({ handleChange }) => (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleChange(props.index)}>
            <AsyncImage
                source={ props.img_src }
                placeholderColor="#fafafa"
                style={{ flex: 1, width: null, height: 200 }}
            />
            <Text>{ props.var_name }</Text>
            <Text>{ props.price }</Text>
            <Text>{ props.sku }</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    )}
</IndexContext.Consumer>
```

Comment: This kind of bug is really hard to fix. Especially when the error message does provide any useful information.

Comment: Unfortunately, it comes down to experience. Once you witnessed this problem or have a good idea about the way jsx and react renderer work, you know what to look for. I believe it happened to me already and I had aha moment.

Comment: This is amazing. Is there any "strict mode" that deals beforehand with ";" ?  It's just syntax, not even types...

Comment: @nicolas No, this is just a human mistake that can't be addressed by the framework more specific than error message does. It's about the correct understanding of JSX syntax. Text outside `{}` is HTML layout, there could be random text instead of `;` with the same result, it's not allowed in <Consumer> children. There's no place for `;` any way because anything inside `{}` is JS expression, while semicolon is used with statements, not expressions.

Answer (score 2):

You may have Imported Context Consumer instead of Provider

Like,

```
 <AuthProvider>
    <App />
</AuthProvider>
```

instead, you may have write

```
  <AuthContext>
    <App />
  </AuthContext>
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem happened with me.

I have written:

```
  <SnackBarContext>
    <App />
  </SnackBarContext>
```

Instead of

```
  <SnackBarContext.Provider>
    <App />
  </SnackBarContext.Provider>
```

I forgot `.Provider` :)