# How to solve the error given by react js like TypeError: render is not a function?

Tags: reactjs

Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { storeProducts, detailProduct } from './data';

const ProductContext = React.createContext(null);
//Provider
//Consumer


class ProductProvider extends Component {
    state = {
        products: storeProducts,
        detailProduct: detailProduct
    }

    handleDetail = () =>{
        console.log('hello from details');

    }

    addToCart = () => {
        console.log('hello from add to cart');

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ProductContext.Provider  value={{
                    ...this.state,
                }}>
            {this.props.children}
            </ProductContext.Provider>
        )
    }
}

const ProductConsumer = ProductContext.Consumer;

export { ProductProvider, ProductConsumer };
```

**error**

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: which version of react-dome are you using ?

Comment: I think this question has already been answered:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54304594/react-context-typeerror-render-is-not-a-function

Comment: @KOTIOS the version is "react-dom": "^16.9.0",

Comment: @WagnerMeyer but it error is come from the <ProductContext.Provider> where i can you ...this.state.

Answer (score 0):

@Anshu, I think the error is coming from the Consumer. Right below the `TypeError: render is not a function`, we can see the `updateContextConsumer` method.

Edited:
So, I think I figured it out. It's really connected to the Consumer.
Where you're using the `<ProductConsumer/>`, you'll need to use a function as his children. Something like:

```
<ProductConsumer>
  { state => (<div>{ JSON.stringify( state ) }</div>) }
</ProductConsumer>
```

I put the code on my GitHub, if you want to understand it better.
https://github.com/wagnermeyer/stackoverflow-issue-57788587

Comment: No . the error is coming from the ...this.state. i find out out i don't know how to solve it.