# Faced TypeError: render is not a function when using Context API

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React ans was learning Context API and during the use of it I faced this error TypeError: render is not a function. I also found the this answer [React Context: TypeError: render is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54304594/react-context-typeerror-render-is-not-a-function) in the platform which is close to my problem but no result. Here is the code I am using:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import MyContext from "../../Containers/Context/Context";
class Track extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MyContext>
        {value => {
          return <div>{value.heading}</div>;
        }}
      </MyContext>
    );
  }
}

export default Track;
```

---

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

const Context = React.createContext();

export class MyContext extends Component {
  state = { track_list: [], heading: "Top Ten Tracks" };
  render() {
    return (
      <Context.Provider value={this.state}>
        {this.props.children}
      </Context.Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default MyContext = Context.Consumer;
```

---

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Header from "../src/Components/Header/Header";
import Search from "../src/Components/Search/Search";
import Tracks from "../src/Components/Tracks/Tracks";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import NotFound from "./Components/NotFound/NotFound";
import MyContext from "./Containers/Context/Context";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MyContext>
        <Router>
          <Fragment>
            <Header />
            <div className="container">
              <Search />
              <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Tracks} />
                <Route component={NotFound} />
              </Switch>
            </div>
          </Fragment>
        </Router>
      </MyContext>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: You never mount the context provider, so why would you expect your consumer to work? FYI, context only works when `Context.Provider` is a parent of `Context.Consumer`. You need to wrap your app in the context provider. Also, look at your export statements. You export `MyContext` as a named export, and you export `Context.Consumer` as `MyContext`(by overwriting the value of MyContext in your export statement) as the default export. there's all kinds of wtf going on here

Comment: @r3wt, thanks dude for your kind attention and help. Gosh so hard to be beginner:)

Comment: is ok, trust me my first journey with context was very similar :-) glad it helped

Comment: @r3wt, sorry dude just wanted to ask you kind advice. Is it ok to use Context API when there is Parent->Child two level relationship instead of prop-drilling? Or Should we consider using Context API when there are more than 3 level relationship? Thank you:)

Comment: a general rule of thumb is that if more than 1 sibling needs access to a state of some parent of `n` depth, then i will probably use a context provider just to avoid the prop drilling. Sometimes this includes a direct child of the parent component, but often the nesting is as you say >=3 deep. Truthfully though, i avoided context at my own peril in the past so now i am much more eager to find ways to make it work, just to avoid the unmaintainability of prop drilling and juggling events and state across multiple components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your export and import statements are problematic.

first you `export class MyContext` then you immediately overwrite `MyContext` with `Context.Consumer`.

Fix your export statements and then fix your imports. import the `Context.Consumer` in file `Track`, and import the `Context.Provider` in file `App`

**Containers/Context/Context.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

const Context = React.createContext();

class MyContextProvider extends Component {
  state = { track_list: [], heading: "Top Ten Tracks" };
  render() {
    return (
      <Context.Provider value={this.state}>
        {this.props.children}
      </Context.Provider>
    );
  }
}

const MyContextConsumer = Context.Consumer;

export {MyContextProvider,MyContextConsumer};
```

**Track.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {MyContextConsumer} from "../../Containers/Context/Context";
class Track extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MyContextConsumer>
        {value => {
          return <div>{value.heading}</div>;
        }}
      </MyContextConsumer>
    );
  }
}

export default Track;
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Header from "../src/Components/Header/Header";
import Search from "../src/Components/Search/Search";
import Tracks from "../src/Components/Tracks/Tracks";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import NotFound from "./Components/NotFound/NotFound";
import {MyContextProvider} from "./Containers/Context/Context";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MyContextProvider>
        <Router>
          <Fragment>
            <Header />
            <div className="container">
              <Search />
              <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Tracks} />
                <Route component={NotFound} />
              </Switch>
            </div>
          </Fragment>
        </Router>
      </MyContextProvider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```